# Brownian motion simulation - scaling issue

Tags: r, brownian-motion, simulations

I'm trying to simulate some BM for 500 observations.

I got correlated increments as I needed and they are not exactly N(0,1), so I standardize them (x-mean(x))/sd(x). But then the resulting Brownian motions are doing a weird elliptic shape and end up back on the x-axis. So I simulated fresh N(0,1) and used the standardizing function on them again (shouldnt do anything, should it?), but got the same result. [image: Simulated BM after normalisation]

Any idea why is that? Why do they all (100 paths) converge exactly to zero? I guess it must be the normalisation function, but I cannot figure out why would they all go to zero because of that?

My code in R:

```
simGBM<-function(cov=TRUE,secs=100,Tau=500,sigma=0.05,neg.cor=0.3){
if(cov==TRUE){
#  s<-apply(simSeries(simCov(secs,neg.cor),Tau),2,normalise)
m<-simCov(secs,neg.cor)
s<-simSeries(m,Tau)
}  else {
s<-matrix(rnorm(secs*Tau),ncol=secs)}


dt<-1/(Tau)
BM<-apply(s,2,function(x) cumsum(sqrt(dt)*x))
GBM<-apply(BM,2,function(x) 100*exp((-0.5*sigma*sigma*dt+sigma*x)))
 if(cov==TRUE) {return(list(GBM=matrix(GBM,ncol=secs),cov=m))}
else{return(matrix(GBM(ncol=secs)))}
  }


normalise<-function(x){
  ( (x-mean(x))/sd(x) )
}
```

The s is either a series that I simulated with a some covariance structure, or pure white noise.
Just to clarify, if I dont use the scaling function everything is **ok** and looks like it works correctly - checked against 'proven correct' examples.

Comment: Do you know hitting time?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm not sure however if we're on the same page. I'm not after when the BM reaches a certain level (stopping time), just was wondering why they converge to zero in the last few observations if I use my normalisation function. If I dont, they make the classical conical shape, not this elipse...

Comment: Can you provide the code you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are running cumsum on a normalised vector - which'll give you zero as the end value for each path.

Also, in the GBM, the drift term (-sigma^2*dT) needs to accumulate over time.

Comment: Yh, that makes sense about the normalised vector, I didnt realise. Because even though they are all white noise, if I substract the actual mean of the series, then I would get cumsum 0, which is why they tend converge to 0. 

Regarding the GBM, I checked it with code of the guys who made the ['pde'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sde/index.html)  package and they accumulate the BM as well and then just put it in the exponential, so they dont in fact accumulate the drift term either....